# How to manage multiple notification in service using alarm manager

Tags: android, service, notifications, title

I have number of toggles like, 2 minute, 4 minute and 24 hours. if user select any one, the service will be start and set repeat time in alarm manager, the Notification will showing for particular selected time.

Now the problem is i want to show the number of title like for *2 minute reminder*, *4 minute reminder* and *24 hours reminder*. how to manage these all the titles in local notification service and manage click event.

My code is [How to keep service alive when remove app from stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44916058/how-to-keep-service-alive-when-remove-app-from-stack)

Please suggest to find solution.

Comment: Can you explain your needs in clear way? What i understood is that you are able to ring alarms at different times but when alarm rings then you want to display the time for which that was set? i.e. if alarms is for 2 minutes then title "2 minutes" should also be there. is it?

Comment: yes if i checked toggle of 2 minute then service will start and alarm manager repeat every 2 minute, and after every 2 minute notification will show with title like *2 minute reminder*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the pendingIntent for your AlarmManager you can put extras and you can pass title to your MyReceiver activity like following.

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(NotificationDemo.this, MyReceiver.class);
myIntent.putExtra("title","2 minutes");
                pendingIntent = 
PendingIntent.getBroadcast(NotificationDemo.this, 0, myIntent, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

All the notifications will have a unique id so you can distinguish them on the basis of their id in the Receiver class. All these must be assigned a unique id when they are created to distinguish between them.

You can also define type of notification, so that you will be able to cast different types of notifications with different push messages and its parameters.

The answer to the question you asked in the comment that to set title of a notification :
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context).setContentTitle("Title of Notification");

Comment: Ok but how to set title? can you describe once!

Comment: When your creating the Notification you can set the title using as follows :  NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =  new NotificationCompat.Builder(context).setContentTitle("Title of Notification");